# Adsorption on solids - homogeneous/heterogeneous surface definition

Tags: solid-state-chemistry, surface-chemistry, adsorption

**How could we define homogeneous and heterogeneous surfaces (rigorously)?**

It is among my exam questions (but I could not find any definition in my textbook or on the internet).

I would say the homogeneous surface is a surface made of one type of molecule (opposite of the heterogeneous surface). But my knowledge about surfaces is very surface (and I am surprised it is listed as an exam question) so are there any other conditions or is it enough?

Comment: Homogeneous surface is not a thing at all.

Comment: Why? Not even in an ideal case?

Comment: We talk of homogeneous _mixtures_ and _reactions_ when there is one phase and no surfaces at all. Otherwise we use the word heterogeneous. That's all.

Comment: Yet it is literally one of the questions which my professor gave me

Comment: @IvanNeretin All depends on context.  We can talk about homogenous/heterogenous surface in context of the surface itself, not the whole system.  Like an object made of solid pure compound can have homogenous surface, but if made of a metallic alloy, it can have heterogenous surface, with properties location dependent.

Comment: Yeah, I guess we can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Homogeneous surface is the surface where we can (in the context of the scenario, like the purpose and  required/available resolution and sensitivity) neglect any surface variability. Otherwise, the surface is heterogeneous.

It is important to say it is relative evaluation. For a set of surfaces, it can reach both extremes like "everything is homogeneous" to "everything is heterogeneous".

A visually homogeneous surface can be considered heterogeneous when evaluated by the enough zooming-in optical or electron microscope.

A visually heterogeneous surface can be considered homogeneous when evaluated from far enough or with low resolution or sensitivity for differences.